# Not display actualized cell value to speed up code

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on Excel 2007. I have a spreadsheet that computes stuff in many many cells. Every time i change a parameter, excel recomputes everything. So far, no problem.

I designed a macro that changes parameters thousand of times. It works fine, but displaying in the cells the new values takes a lot of time.
Is there a way to do :

new param -> compute -> the cell value has been modified -> the new value **IS NOT** displayed in the cell

*INSTEAD of the classic*

new param -> compute -> the cell value has been modified -> the new cell value is displayed in the cell

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: try before updating Application.ScreenUpdating = False and to revert back Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Comment: Although that is an option, it is more useful to see what has been written (in case of errors) so manual calculation is a better way to go IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch `Application.ScreenUpdating` property to `False` before calculations and set it back to `True` after.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to my question, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can make out, it sounds like you are wanting these:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Or non-programatically in 07:

[image: http://img.chandoo.org/optimize/set-formulas-to-manual-calcualtion-mode-speedsheet-optimization-tips.png]

Comment: Add `Application.Calculate` to execute a single calculation.